# Kubernetes Ingress - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: python, java, kubernetes, websocket, socket.io

I've confirmed this works locally, but when deploying, there looks to be a breakdown in communication.

I have this ingress defined:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}
  labels:
    name: {{ .Values.name }}
spec:
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.host }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Values.name }}-service
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      - path: /socket.io/spectrogram
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: spectrogram-ms-backend-service
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.service.spectrogramMsPort }}
      - path: /socket.io/anomaly
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: anomaly-detection-ms-service
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.service.anomalyMsPort }}
```

And here are the values you can't see:

```
service:
  spectrogramMsPort: 8080
  anomalyMsPort: 5000
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 4200
  protocol: TCP
```

The communicate to the /socket.io/spectrogram works fine, but not to the /socket.io/anomaly path.

Here is the error that's showing in my Chrome console:

```
polyfills.b93b12e29a67f209.js:1 
        
        
       GET http://<host_redacted>/socket.io/anomaly/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OnbiQow 502 (Bad Gateway)
```

In my Angular frontend, I have 2 WebSockets:

Anomaly:

```
  constructor(@Inject(ANOMALY_DETECTION_HTTP_WS_URL) url: string) {
    super(url,  { path: '/socket.io/anomaly', onlyBinaryUpgrades: true });
    this.anomalyMessageSubject =
    new BehaviorSubject<AnomalyMessage | null>(null);
    this.anomalyMessage$ = this.anomalyMessageSubject.asObservable();
    this.connect();
    this.on(this.eventName, (payload: Uint8Array) => {
      this.handleMessage(payload);
    });
  }
```

Spectrogram:

```
  constructor(@Inject(SPECTROGRAM_HTTP_WS_URL) url: string) {
    super(url,  { path: '/socket.io/spectrogram', onlyBinaryUpgrades: true });
    this.spectrogramResponseSubject =
      new BehaviorSubject<BucketedDetections | null>(null);
    this.spectrogramResponse$ = this.spectrogramResponseSubject.asObservable();
    this.connect();
    this.on(this.eventName, (payload: Uint8Array) => {
      this.handleMessage(payload);
    });
  }
```

The spectrogram backend is a Java Springboot backend, where I am hosting it on localhost:8080, and setting the socket.io context to /socket.io/spectrogram. This applies to both my local instance and the pod, localhost:8080 for both.

The anomaly backend is a Python application, where I am hosting it on localhost:5000, an setting the socket.io path to /socket.io/anomaly. Same again for local and pod.

```
class AnomalyDetectionWebSocket(WebSocket):
    """
    Extends the base WebSocket class for Anomaly specific usage.
    Publishes to the ANOMALY event name.
    """
    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(host, port)
        self.namespace = '/client'
        self.event_name = 'ANOMALY'
        self.app = web.Application()
        self.sio.attach(self.app, socketio_path='/socket.io/anomaly')
```

Again, this all works locally, I can see my frontend connecting to both backends when I run it locally. But just in my Kubernetes deployment, there is some sort of error that I can't find.

Here are my services:

```
NAME                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                               AGE
anomaly-detection-ms-service     ClusterIP   10.43.82.60     <none>        5000/TCP                              4m7s
cassandra                        ClusterIP   10.43.170.166   <none>        9042/TCP,8080/TCP                     14d
cassandra-headless               ClusterIP   None            <none>        7000/TCP,7001/TCP,7199/TCP,9042/TCP   14d
ewsm-demo-service                ClusterIP   10.43.179.244   <none>        4200/TCP                              15d
redis-service                    ClusterIP   10.43.30.227    <none>        6379/TCP                              16d
spectrogram-ms-backend-service   ClusterIP   10.43.77.213    <none>        8080/TCP                              16d
```